# SharePoint 365 access using NewtonSoft and Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, json.net, sharepoint-online

My end goal is to update file metadata after uploading a new file with defaults.

My program uses Visual Basic to create the document and then upload it to a synced folder. This works well.

I have spent some time researching how to complete the file meta data step and believe I should use NewtsonSoft.json and System.net

The steps that I have completed so far are below:

1. Create an app in Azure Active Directory and generate a secret key.
2. Use some code from the net and the id's from 1 above to generate an access token.
3. This seems to work.

Public Function GetAccessToken() As String

```
    Dim tenantId = "My Tenant ID"
    Dim clientId = "MY Client ID"
    Dim authorityUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"
    Dim redirectUri = "http://localhost"
    Dim scopes = New List(Of String) From {
        "https://myaddress.sharepoint.com/.default"
    }
    Dim clientSecret = "My Secret ID"
    Dim confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).WithAuthority(New Uri(authorityUri)).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).Build()
    Dim accessTokenRequest = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
    Dim accessToken = accessTokenRequest.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken
    'MsgBox(accessToken)

    Return accessToken

End Function
```

I then use the below to get the ID of the drive where a file is stored.

```
Public Function GetDriveID(ByVal strMainSite As String) As String
        Dim strDriveId As String = ""
        Dim url As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}"
        'Replace {drive-id} with the actual ID of the SharePoint Drive you want to access.

        Dim client As New WebClient()
        strAccessToken = GetAccessToken()
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer  " & strAccessToken)
        'Replace {access-token} with a valid access token obtained from SharePoint.

        Dim response As String = client.DownloadString(url)
        Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(response)

        Dim driveId As String = jsonObject("id").ToString()

        Return driveId

    End Function
```

These makes use of the below:

```
Public Class SharePointClient
        Private ReadOnly baseUrl As String
        Private ReadOnly httpClient As HttpClient

        Public Sub New(baseUrl As String, accessToken As String)
            Me.baseUrl = baseUrl.TrimEnd("/")
            Me.httpClient = New HttpClient()
            Me.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken)
        End Sub

        Public Async Function GetDriveIdFromNameAsync(siteId As String, driveName As String) As Task(Of String)
            Dim endpoint As String = $"{baseUrl}/sites/{siteId}/drives"
            'Me.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strAccessToken)
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint)


            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
                Dim drives As JArray = json("value")

                For Each drive As JObject In drives
                    If drive("name").ToString().Equals(driveName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                        Return drive("id").ToString()
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            Return Nothing
        End Function

    End Class
```

I'm stuck at taking the drive ID and a filename to get the filename ID which I then believe I can use to update the metadata.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to exactly what your question is.  Any chance you could narrow this down into a [mcve] showing just where you are stuck, with dummy values we can use to test your code ourselves?  For instance, what is the value of the string `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, and what updates you want to make to it?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. Im trying to use the file ID to update the metadata as the next step. I have had to remove any information that links back to our Tenant in Office 365. response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() in the block Public Async Function GetDriveIdFromNameAsync(siteId As String, driveName As String) As Task(Of String) gets a list of all the 'drives' on the Sharepoint site = siteID. You can then look for driveName and get the ID. The block returns the drive ID from siteID for drive named driveName.